# Picture is not showing in Gallery App in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to create a picture and save it into one directory of the SD card programmatically but when I go to gallery then these picture doesn't show there. It shows when I open any SD card browser app.

Is there any way to force so that picture appear in Gallery App also at the same time when I am saving the picture in my directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the Gallery App is so designed to not support Bitmap format. Hence there is no way you can modify that. My guess :-)

Comment: @Nabin Bitmaps means here pictures

Comment: You mean bitmap objects? I think alot of people will get confused :-)

Comment: photo like png, jpg etc

Comment: did you try restarting the system? my guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system does not scan the disk content all the time, it would kill the performances.
When you add a picture that the Gallery needs to pick-up, use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This will allow the mediaScanner to have a look at the file immediately.
Note : if the file is incorrect for some reason, it will not have any effect.